# If a tree $T$ contains a perfect matching, then $n(T)$ is even.

Tags: proof-verification, graph-theory

I would like to use this lemma in a proof, though I would like to vet it out first.

**Proof:** Assuming that $T$ contains a perfect matching, $M$, we have that $M$ saturates every vertex in $T$. Since there are two vertices for each edge, $n(T)=2|M|$. Furthermore, any integer multiplied by two is even, thus we have that $n(T)$ is even.

Thoughts?

Comment: After reading my own question, it seems that this lemma can be generalized to any graph $G$. hmm...

Comment: What is $n(T)$? I'm not familiar with that notation. I've also taken the liberty to add the proof-verification tag to your question; please feel free to rollback if you wish.

Comment: Yes, and yes this is for graphs $G$.

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut, $n(T)$ is the vertex set of the tree $T$, and thank you for including the tag. I'm rather new to MSE.